# Logstash, Filebeat, ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have 2 servers, one with my ELK (each of those in a separate container) and a second server with my application (with centos system). I would like to read logs by Logstash (or Filebeat) from my server with the application. I don't want to install Filebeat or Logstash on my server where an application is. 
Any idea? 
I tried using Logstash file plugin with the path like myserver$/var/www/awesome_log.log but this not works.

Thanks

Comment: What is your application written in? Log appenders are probably the best option here.

Comment: Since you don't want to install filebeat or logstash on the server your application is running, your application will need to send the logs to logstash itself, you can send it using `tcp`, `udp`, `http` or `syslog`. Logstash file input and filebeat only works when installed in the machine where the logs are being written.